# Code working perfectly but sending multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code with I use in inserting into the database and it is working perfectly fine except it sends the data 3 times instead of once and I don't understand the reason it does that. I have read through the code.

```js
// Form validation
$('.ui.form')
    .form({
        fields: {
            title: ['empty'],
            description: ['empty'],
            status: ['empty'],

        },
        onSuccess: function () {
            $("#titlediv").addClass("disabled");
            $("#descriptiondiv").addClass("disabled");
            $("#statusdiv").addClass("disabled");
            $("#contentdiv").addClass("disabled");
            $("#guideindi").fadeIn("slow");

            // Getting textbox value
            var title = $('#title').val();
            var description = $('#description').val();
            var status = $('#statusdiv').dropdown('get value');
            var content = CKEDITOR.instances['content'].getData();
            var date_added = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');
            var date_update = "";
            var added_by = localStorage.getItem("user");

            // Form append
            var data = new FormData();
            data.append('title', title);
            data.append('description', description);
            data.append('status', status);
            data.append('content', content);
            data.append('date_added', date_added);
            data.append('date_update', date_update);
            data.append('added_by', added_by);

            var admin = new XMLHttpRequest();

            admin.open("POST", "http://localhost/Hajjapi/public/api/hajj/add", false);
            admin.send(data);

            if (admin.readyState === 4) {
                if (admin.status === 200) {

                } else {

                }
            } else {
                $('#guidemsg').html(admin.statusText);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you check how many jquery you are calling ? , Like 
<script src="jquery.js"></script> .

Comment: Sorry to be that guy but... this isn't a minimal working example.